# Steams Servers Are To Busy To Complete Installation?

Tags: steam, portal-2

I had a problem with Portal 2 on steam a bit ago where when I tried to launch it after the creepy Valve intro the game would crash.  I went to validate my files and after I did that I  opened the game when I saw a window that said, completing installation.  When it reaches 100% it says that Steam's servers are to busy.  I have tried it multiple times as well as early in the morning and late at night.  How can I complete my installation of the validated file?

Comment: That sometimes happens. Just wait a few hours or a day and it works eventually.

Comment: I have waited for about 2 to three weeks and have tried around 20 times

Comment: Try deleting the local cache files and redownloading it.

Comment: I might do that as a last resort because it took me about 5 hours to install it at first

Comment: It's better than two to three weeks without success. I had the exact problem you described with Portal 2 and I remember having to reinstall it to fix the problem. (I thought I just waited but now I remember having to reinstall). I'm not sure what causes this.

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: Please tell me if it works so I may post this as an answer.

Comment: I have this exact problem all the time.  In my case, my antivirus is the problem.  I turn off McAfee real time scanning while it installs and re-enable it after.  If you have antivirus you should try this or add Steam as an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that answer [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?s=bed05f70fd56185320bcc00debd78963&t=1940717&page=3) and it seems like it helped a lot of people with the same problem.

---

I think it was a side effect of the anti-piracy protection implemented by Valve.

Portal 2 makes use of a Steamworks feature called "Custom Executable Generation": the  Portal 2 executable (portal2.exe, plus some Steam-related DLLs) is not downloaded with the other game files. When the game is started for the first time after an update/new installation has been performed, Steam sends a request to the Steam servers so that the custom-made Portal 2 executable (tied to the Steam account) can be generated and then downloaded (the "Installing..." operation you can see during the first run is actually the executable download; also, the one or two files that can not be validated when you verify Portal 2's game cache integrity are the custom executable and libraries).

The latest update triggered this mechanism and, when many Portal 2 players tried to launch the game again, the Steam servers were probably overloaded by generation requests, hence the error message. I just attempted to launch the game again and it worked for me, if not just wait or choose another (less overloaded) content server from the Settings dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Try deactivating your antivirus and your firewall while installing your game. This will often fix your problems.

If that doesn't help, try selecting a different Steam server, and install it again.